# Failing to npm install socket.io, notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, npm, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to "npm install socket.io" on a Ubuntu EC2 instance and getting this error.  Does this mean I cannot use Ubuntu?  Or is there a way to fix this?

```
$ npm install socket.io

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-03-15T00_57_15_115Z-debug.log




$ node --version
v8.9.4
$ npm --version
5.7.1
```

Here is the debug log it referred to:

https://gist.github.com/lampshade9909/57c631be80a75c1675c315de05e51747

It seems that I may need to install an older version of node.  I'm trying 6.10 and it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu and get that error all the time. I believe fsevents@1.1.3 is for OS x . Linux system ignores fsevents whereas mac will install it.

Comment: So I cannot use this on Ubuntu?  I wonder if there is a version of it which I can.